# How to update React state immediately when dependency changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have a context that keeps the pages data and history, and returns the current page data:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { createContext, ReactNode, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

interface PageDataContextReturn {
    data: any,
    setData: (data: any) => void,
}
const PageDataContext = createContext<PageDataContextReturn>({ data: null, setData: () => { });

export default PageDataContext;

interface PageState {
    id: string,
    data: any
}

export function PageDataContextProvider({ children, initialPageData }: { children: ReactNode, pageData: any }) {
    const [data, setData] = useState<PageState[]>([{ id: 'inital', data: initialPageData }]);
    const router = useRouter()
    const isFirstUpdate = useRef(true);

    function updateCurrentPage(data: any) {
        setData(curr => {
            curr[curr.length - 1].data =
                typeof data === 'function'
                    ? data(curr[curr.length - 1].data)
                    : data;
            // in [...  ] because otherwise react won't rerender.
            return [...curr];
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
            // so it won't recreate first state
            if (isFirstUpdate.current) {
                isFirstUpdate.current = false;
                return;
            }

            const linkId = router.query.linkId as string || 'initial';

            for (const [index, item] of data.entries()) {
                if (item.id === linkId) {
                    return setData(curr => curr.slice(0, index + 1))
                }
            }

            setData(curr => [...curr, { id: linkId, data: newPageData.current }]);
    }, [router])

    return (
        <PageDataContext.Provider value={{ data: data[data.length - 1].data, setData: updateCurrentPage }}>{children}</PageDataContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

The problem is, that because the useEffect is running after the render, there is one render where the data state is not updated and returns the previous page data. I need that the state will be updated to the new page immediately when the router is changed, and not after the render.
I know this is just how useEffect works, but I also can't remove the useEffect because I need the code to run only when the route is changed. also, setting the state without useEffect will cause an infinite renders loop.

How can I make the state update immediately when the route is changed, and not after the render?

Comment: `useLayoutEffect` is what you're looking for. But also, not everything needs to be a state: if you're just deriving a value from something else, `useMemo` is instantaneous and appropriate.

Comment: @Sheraff Thanks, I'll check it out. about the useMemo, it is not possible because the state saves different data that only corresponds to the current page id, and it is also changed separately with the updateCurrentPage. The router is only used to check what page is it, but the data has to be saved in state.

Comment: @Sheraff it actually still doesn't work even with useLayoutEffect, the context still has one render that returns the previous page data, it doesn't change immediately when the route changes.

Comment: Try use a function to initialize your state.

Comment: @PeterT what do you mean? can you give an example?

Comment: They mean `useState(() => /* init state here */)`